# python strptime() 第一引数エラーについて

Tags: python, flask

strptimeの第一引数は、文字列にする必要があります（TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not None）がでてしまいます。
create.htmlのフォームから送られてくるデーターは、文字列になるとのことで、
strptime()の第一引数は、文字列になっているはずですが、なぜか、エラーと
なってしまっています。

こちらの解決方法についてご教示いただければと思います。

ただし、DBへの登録はできております。

```py
# app.py

from datetime import datetime

from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
URI = 'sqlite:///todo.db'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = URI
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Post(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(140), nullable=False)
    detail = db.Column(db.String(100))
    due = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False)


@app.cli.command('initialize_DB')
def initialize_DB():
    db.create_all()




@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request == 'GET':
        posts = Post.query.all()
        return render_template('index.html', posts=posts)
    else:
        title = request.form.get('title')
        detail = request.form.get('detail')
        due = request.form.get('due')

        due = datetime.strptime(due, '%Y-%m-%d') # ここでエラー
    
        new_posts = Post(title=title, detail=detail, due=due)
        db.session.add(new_posts)
        db.session.commit()

        return redirect('/')


@app.route('/create')
def create():
    title = '登録画面'
    return render_template('create.html', title=title)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

```html
<! -- create.html -->

{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<form action="/" method="POST">
    <label for="title">Title</label>
    <input type="text" name="title">
    <label for="detail">Detail</label>
    <input type="text" name="detail">
    <label for="due">Due</label>
    <input type="date" name="due" required>
    <input type="submit" value="Create">
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: `if request == 'GET':` としていますが、HTTP REQUEST METHOD なので、`if request.method == 'GET':` とするのではないでしょうか。

Comment: ありがとうございまう。上記アドバイスで解決致しました。完全に見落としでした。

Answer (score 2):

`if request == 'GET':` としていますが、HTTP REQUEST METHOD なので、`if request.method == 'GET':`

と修正したことで解決しました。